# Can somebody help me resolve some frustrating conflicts with Java, Ant, and Eclipse on a 64 bit Windows 8.1 system?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, ant

Background: I’m setting up an automated build system, with Selenium (Java), Ant, Eclipse and Jenkins on a virtual machine running a 64 bit version of Windows 8.1.

Problem #1-
The latest version of the 64 bit JDK (1.8.0.72) doesn’t seem to include tools.jar, which ant (version 1.9.6) seems to depend on.
My solution has been to download the 32 bit version of the JDK and set all environmental variables accordingly.

Which leads to Problem #2-
Now that I have reset my environment to point to the 32 bit JDK, I can no longer start Eclipse without an error message “Failed to load the JNI shared library.”  I have tried to resolve this error by adding a line to my eclipse config file to point to the correct JVM (jvm.dll), but that isn’t working.

Comment: I've just downloaded jdk-8u72-windows-x64.exe from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and ran it. It installed both jdk and jre as usual, jdk contains tools.jar in the lib directory.

Comment: You can't run a 64 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit JVM, they must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: Have you searched inside Eclipse configs any config screen to set up ant runtime vars?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick suggestions.  I have come up with a solution (or at least a decent workaround).

Download 32 bit and the 64 bit version of the JDK.  Set my JAVA_HOME var to point to the 64 bit JDK, which satisfies Eclipse, and then copy the tools.jar file included with the 32 bit JDK to the 64 bit JDK.  Not very elegant, but for now it seems to be working.  Ant and Eclipse are both happy.

It is strange that downloading the 64 bit version of the JDK doesn't include tools.jar.  I tried 8u71 and 8u72 for windows 64 bit without any luck.